# How to update the browser cache on log in / log out?

Tags: php

I am using browser caching to speed up my PHP website. If a user visits a page before logging in and comes back to the page again after logging in, the page doesn't get updated with the contents that are only visible to the logged-in users.

**i.e.** The "***Log in***" link on the header menu doesn't change to the "***Log out***" link if the user visited the page before logging in. And if they visited a new page after logging in, the "***Log out***" link on the header menu doesn't change to the "***Log in***" link even after log out.

**Here is a sample code**

```
<h2>Contact Form</h2>
<form method="post" action="" onsubmit="">
    <?php
      if (logged_in() === false) {
        ?>
        Name*
        <input type="text" name="name" required />
        Email*
        <input type="email" name="email" required />
        <?php
      }
    ?>
    Message*
    <textarea name="message" rows="12"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="contact" value="Send Message" />
</form>
```

It would be a huge help for me if someone could help me on this issue.

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: Can you share your code or maybe the approach you are using?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by ___Browser Caching___, because all browsers cache things, are you doing something specific to make the browser do something other than its standard actions, and if so, what?

Comment: @ Ghazni Ali - Thanks for the quick response. Please give me a moment, I'll update a sample code in my question.

Comment: @ RiggsFolly - Thank you for the response. - Nothing unusual. The usual one achieving via `ExpiresActive On`. The issue started only after turning it on. But I can't turn this off because Google PageSpeed insights suggesting this on.

Comment: Then it does not make sense to cache these pages.

Comment: @Ghazni Ali - The sample code has been added. Could you please check and update me?

Comment: Share logged_in() function code this code is fine. Also share logout code as well.

Comment: @Ghazni Ali - The question is not about the Log-in or log-out issue. The issue is about purely browser caching. Could you please explain why are you asking these?

Comment: What are the HTTP headers that your PHP website is sending to the browser?
Have you got an Apache or NGINX config that sends a header telling the browser that he can cache it for a while? Typically you could have an `Expire` or `Cache-Control` header doing that. I would set `Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, private` for all HTML sent and set `Cache-Control: max-age=31536000` (= 1 year) and `Vary: Accept-Encoding` for all static files such as JS, CSS, images, etc. If you update a static file then change the URL in the HTML by adding `?v=2`, `?v=3` and so on to force a new download.

Comment: @ Patrick Janser - Apache! I have already tried with headers you suggested. Nothing works for me. Could you please explain how to add the URL versions to my site? I think it would work!

Comment: By the way, for the HTML responses, you should also set the HTTP header `Vary: Cookie,Accept-Encoding` (and perhaps also `Accept-Language` if you have language detection on the homepage) so that proxies and reverse-proxies don't mess up cached results since the cookie will identify a session and the page will be built for this specific user and not for anybody else. But correct me if I'm wrong but I don't think the `Vary` header will be used by the browser itself. It's only for proxy layers between your server and the customer.

Comment: Is your website accessible somewhere? This would be much easier for us to see what's happening. The version in the URL is only if you want to cache static files, which I really recommend doing! Ex: you have a file *css/theme.css* and in the HTML you have to put `<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/css/theme.css?v=1" />` and each time you update your CSS, just increment this number to deploy it in all browsers.

Comment: Please add **all** clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: I think that's called cache busting like   `<script src="<?php echo"my-script.js?rand=".rand(10,1000);?>"></script>`

Comment: @EmmaMarshall Except that here **we don't want to do that** as we want to cache static files (so never do a rand since nothing will be ever cached neighter in control) but not cache the HTML response. **The problematic is on the HTML page generated by the PHP** and not the files linked and loaded by the browser.

Comment: @ Emma Marshall - Thank you for your support. Unfortunately, I'm not using any external scripts.

Comment: You have something like where user not supposed to access redirect them on correct location when session not found ?

Comment: @PatrickJanser - I think your suggestion might work. Let me try and update you. Thank you so much for spending your time to help me.

Comment: Great! So what did you do? It would be great for others that you post the answer to your problem.

Comment: Nothing much. Just added the `Cache-Control` and `Vary` headers and started working flawlessly. Is it really good idea to post the answer myself?

Comment: @PatrickJanser - I have a personal question, and I don't know where to ask. How is the reputation works here in Stack Overflow? Because the user `RiggsFolly` has over 80k reputation and he couldn't help me at all. And the other side, you have less than a 2k reputation, and you were able to help me and give the possible suggestions for my issue. I wonder how this platform works?

Comment: @Tksrm : Yes, you're right, I should ideally answer if I want to get a few points of reputation, haha! I don't know what happens if you answer yourself. Happy if I could help. I'll add my answer below so that everybody gets it and then the question will also be set to "solved" which is probably better :-)

Comment: @PatrickJanser - I can now clearly understand why your reputation is lower than other less helpful persons. `Good people don't work for fame. They focus on helping people without more expectation.` By the way, you've done a great job!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll formulate the answer based on the comments we had together.

### Check the HTTP headers sent to the browser

The HTTP headers sent by *PHP*, *Apache*, *NGINX* or whatever is running on your server or even passing through (such as reverse proxies like *Varnish*) will inform the browser what to do with the response.

If you have an `Expire` or `Cache-Control` HTTP header that says the page can be cached then effectively the browser won't retrieve the page again once you're logged in.

**If you don't want your dynamic pages to be cached** you have to set the HTTP header in adequation, ex: `Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, private`

This could be done in PHP:

```php
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, private');
```

It can also be done later in your web server config for page requests handled by PHP.
By the way, the web server can override what PHP says, so you have to check the output yourself with the browser. Even some other layers such as proxies could alter the HTTP headers.

#### The `Vary` HTTP header

If your server responds for a given URL in different ways then it has to inform that the response can vary depending on something. Typically, almost all assets should be compressed to *gzip* or *brotli* to save bandwidth. But not all browsers handle *brotli* compression. So when they do the request, they say what they can handle, ex: `accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br`. Here, the browser can handle `br` = *brotli*.

The response will then be compressed with *brotli* to reduce the size. But if a reverse proxy caches it and someone else comes with a browser that doesn't handle *brotli* then we'll be in trouble. This is why the server should inform all caching layers that the response varies depending on the `Accept-Encoding` header by returning `Vary: Accept-Encoding`.

It's also common to have a language detection script for the homepage URL (if you hit the domain without a language path). In this case, we have to send `Vary: Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language`

For the HTML generated by PHP, it would also be important to say that the response can vary depending on the `Cookie` header. This is because a page for a specific user could be allowed for caching in private mode, let's say for a minute or more but it should not be messed up with another user's page.
So in PHP, you could do:

```php
header('Vary: Accept-Language, Accept-Encoding, Cookie');
```

#### Caching static files and re-deploying them

**In terms of performance, it's important to cache static data**. So typically this should be done for all assets such as CSS, JS, images, favicons, fonts, etc. They are not dynamic so they can be stored for ages. This can be done by setting `Cache-Control: max-age=31536000` for these static files.

If you change a CSS rule, the CSS file won't be re-downloaded by a visitor that already came before. But it's not a problem because your HTML can point to a new URL for this same static file. This can be done by adding a query parameter in the URL of this asset:

```php
<?php

// Increment the version when you change your CSS.
// This can even be done automatically during deployment.
// You could also use the file timestamp or an hash instead.
$css_version = 3;

echo "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" media=\"all\" href=\"/css/theme.css?version=$css_version\" />\n";
```

#### *Apache* config for compressed static files

The idea to have a performance improvement is to compress all CSS and JS files. This can be done by minifying, aggregating and then compressing.

I use *NodeJS* and made some *NPM scripts* to do that. [There's plenty of info about that on the web](https://www.google.com/search?q=nodejs+npm+scripts+minify+gzip+brotli)

Then you need to add a few rules in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect to HTTPS if we are not in HTTPS:
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Redirect to www.example.com if it's example.com without the www. prefix:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
# But don't do it if it's on the local development machine (ex: example.com.local).
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !\.local$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# If the URL looks like only having the language in the path, such as
# https://www.example.com/de or https://www.example.com/EN then rewrite it
# to index.php?lang=XX where XX is the captured language.
# It's case insensitive with [NC] because PHP makes it to lowercase after.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(en|de|fr|es|it)$ index.php?lang=$1 [NC]

# Serve brotli compressed assets if they exist.
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} br
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.br -f
RewriteRule (.*\.(?:css|js|svg|ico))(?:$|\?) $1.br [NC,L]

# Serve gzipped compressed assets if they exist.
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.gz -f
RewriteRule (.*\.(?:css|js|svg|ico))(?:$|\?) $1.gz [NC,L]

# Set MIME types and avoid double compression done by some Apache modules.
RewriteRule \.css\.(gz|br) - [NC,E=no-gzip:1,E=no-brotli:1,T=text/css]
RewriteRule \.js\.(gz|br)  - [NC,E=no-gzip:1,E=no-brotli:1,T=application/javascript]
RewriteRule \.svg\.(gz|br) - [NC,E=no-gzip:1,E=no-brotli:1,T=image/svg+xml]
RewriteRule \.ico\.(gz|br) - [NC,E=no-gzip:1,E=no-brotli:1,T=image/x-icon]

# Tell proxies to cache files separately depending on the Accept-Encoding header
# value sent by the browser. This is because we respond with different content
# encodings (none, brotli, gzip) for the same requested URL. We'll only do that
# for the static files. For pages, we'll let the PHP app set the Vary header.
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:css|js|svg|ico)(?:\.(?:gz|br))?$">
    Header append Vary Accept-Encoding
</FilesMatch>

# Send the correct encoding header for *.gz files served instead of the original.
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:css|js|svg|ico)\.gz$">
    Header set Content-Encoding gzip
</FilesMatch>

# Send the correct encoding header for *.br files served instead of the original.
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:css|js|svg|ico)\.br$">
    Header set Content-Encoding br
</FilesMatch>

# Set a long cache age of 2 years for all static files.
# You have to change the URL if you update the file. Be aware
# that if you upload documents to your website you might have
# to disable this rule in the uploaded folder.
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:br|css|gif|gz|ico|jpe?g|js|png|svg)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=63072000, public"
</FilesMatch>

# PHP can be configured to compress automatically the output if the browser
# accepts gzip compression. According to the documentation it is more effective
# this way than using ob_start('ob_gzhandler') in the PHP code.
# If output_compression is enabled then it will automatically set the
# "Vary: Accept-Encoding" HTTP header.
php_flag  zlib.output_compression On
php_value zlib.output_compression_level 9

# Hide PHP's X-Powered-By HTTP header if php.ini doesn't already do it.
Header unset X-Powered-By
```

### Compress PHP's output with gzip

As you see in the *Apache* config above, we can enable the
`zlib.output_compression` functionnality of PHP, which will
compress the output if the browser handles it and the `Vary`
HTTP header will also be automatically set.

But if you cannot enable it via *Apache* or *php.ini* then you
can still do the compression yourself in the PHP code with the
output buffering. Just put this piece of code in your PHP before
outputing any text:

```php
// If zlib.output_compression=On then the output will be automatically compressed
// and the "Vary: Accept-Encoding" header will be set too. But if it's not enabled
// then we could compress the page ourselves with PHP's output buffering.
if (preg_match('/^(Off|0)$/i', ini_get('zlib.output_compression'))) {
    // If the browser accepts gzip then compress with PHP's output buffering.
    if (preg_match('/\bgzip\b/', $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'])) {
        // No need to set the "Vary: Accept-Encoding" header because this is
        // already done by ob_gzhandler() called below.
        ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
    }
}

// Hide the X-Powered-By HTTP header if expose_php=Off cannot be set.
if (function_exists('header_remove')) {
    header_remove('X-Powered-By');
} else {
    // We cannot remove it but we can set it to empty.
    header('X-Powered-By:');
    // We'll also try to remove it in the .htaccess file.
}
```